# How to list all partitions in gremlin?

Tags: gremlin

Is there anyway to list all partition keys with gremlin API? 
I knew that I can create a PartitionStrategy while creating a graph. However, how can I know which partitions already have in a graph?

Comment: this question should not have been closed. it asks a very specific question assuming you are familiar with the Gremlin/TinkerPop domain.

Answer (score 5):

In the context of `PartitionStrategy`, there are only two ways to know what partitions are in the graph:

1. You know and keep track of the various partitions yourself as they are created.
2. You query the graph for the partitions by getting the unique list of partition names in the partition key: `g.V().values("nameOfYourPartitionKey").dedup()`

Obviously, the second approach listed above could be very expensive since it is a global traversal. For especially large graphs you may need to use an OLAP-style traversal with [SparkGraphComputer](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#sparkgraphcomputer).

Comment: "You know and keep track of the various partitions yourself as they are created"
Could you suggest how please ?

Comment: i just meant that you name them as they are created so you must know what they were called at that time. `PartitionStrategy` doesn't name partitions for you. i suppose you would only use 2 if you knew absolutely nothing about the graph and needed to get the partition names.